# Change position of a div with jquery onresize

Tags: javascript, css, html, responsive

I'm currently working on a web project for my company and I'm in trouble. I have code like so:

```
//CSS
.home-panel{
   z-index: 0;
   width: 1800px;
   height: 2100px;
   background: gray;
   transform: skew(0deg,-55deg) translateY(-1920px);
}
.ultimate-hero{
   height:100vh;
   overflow:hidden;
}


  //HTML
  <div class="ultimate-hero">
    <div class="home-panel">
    </div>
  </div>


 //JS
 $(window).resize(function() {
    //get dimensions
    var height = $(window).height();
    var width = $(window).width();
    $('.home-panel').css({
   'transform' : 'skew(0deg,-55deg) translateY(-'+width+'px)'
     });
  });
```

I want to move `.home-panel` when the browser is resizing, but that code apparently does the reverse from what I expected. So how do I fix that?

Thank you.

I should mention this earlier, i want something like `.home-panel` from this website http://espn.com/espn/feature/story/_/id/19742921/espn-body-issue-2017 or at least closer. If you have better way to do that, please help me.

Comment: can I see your whole code?

Comment: Yeah sure, you can see it right there http://69authentic.com/fancy/hero.html

Answer (score 0):

```
.home-panel{
   z-index: 0;
   width: 1800px;
   height: 2100px;
   background: gray;
   /*transform: skew(0deg,-55deg) translateY(-1920px);*/
}
```

Try to remove `transform: skew(0deg,-55deg) translateY(-1920px);`

```
 //JS
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var height = $(window).height();
    var width = $(window).width();
    $('.home-panel').css({
   'transform' : 'skew(0deg,-55deg) translateY(-'+width+'px)'
     });

 });

 $(window).resize(function() {
    //get dimensions
    var height = $(window).height();
    var width = $(window).width();
    $('.home-panel').css({
   'transform' : 'skew(0deg,-55deg) translateY(-'+width+'px)'
     });
  });
```

Comment: Hmm i'm not sure, because it'll mess the UI. but thanks i'll try that

Comment: @naovalluthfi Would you try to add JS?

Comment: Yeah, like what?

Comment: @naovalluthfi My Answer.

Comment: Hmm no sorry, what i expect is the <code>.home-panel</code> is move to the left when the browser is risizing, my code does the reverse form what is expected, your code make the ,<code>.home-panel</code> still in the same place. But thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.home-panel').css({
    'transform': 'skew(0deg,-55deg) translateY(-'+(1920+1800- width)+'px)'
});
```

Comment: Wow thanks, that very helpful it's closer to what i wanted. But do you know how to do this http://http://espn.com/espn/feature/story/_/id/19742921/espn-body-issue-2017 and by this i mean .home-panel from that website is pretty awesome, how to do that?

Comment: @naovalluthfi   that `transform:matrix(cos,sin,-sin,cos,0,0)`  tells us  it applies `rotate` transformation. cut the page into several parts . when window resizes, adjust `height` `width` and `left` of each part.

Comment: Should i start from the beggining to do that?

Comment: @naovalluthfi it is ok to use espn way. you could develop your own way to achieve similar effect. just use your imagination.